Efficiently Collecting Data from HTTP API and Inserting into PostgreSQL using Apache NiFi
I need advice on handling a large number of HTTP API requests and data processing.
Problem:
I must collect JSON data from an HTTP API (REST service), extract ten fields from the JSON response, and insert them into a PostgreSQL database. The challenge is that:

There are 200,000 unique URLs to query, and each URL must be requested five times daily, resulting in 1 million requests daily.

The requests are grouped and distributed throughout the day. For example:


08:00 AM:
abc.com/data/x/1
abc.com/data/x/2
...
abc.com/data/x/50000

09:00 AM:
abc.com/data/y/1
abc.com/data/y/2
...
abc.com/data/y/50000

And so on until all 1 million requests are made in a day.

Although I know the URLs ahead of time, there will be 200-300 URL changes every day.

What I've Considered:
Since NiFi doesn’t have built-in looping, I considered a few strategies but am unsure if they're good practices:

A separate processor for each request – Clearly not feasible with 1 million requests.

One flow file per time group (containing a URL per line) — Processing each line might affect NiFi performance. I also don’t know how to rate-limit the requests using this method.

Creating 200,000 files in folders for each time group and processing files one by one — Do I need to create 200,000 files for each time? Also, is this efficient?


Prior Research
I saw similar questions and how-tos for multiple URLs, which involved 100-200 requests. However, my scale is very different.
Question:
What is the best practice in Apache NiFi for efficiently handling 1 million HTTP requests daily, distributing them evenly over time, and inserting the data into a PostgreSQL database?
I’m relatively new to NiFi and would appreciate any detailed steps, processor suggestions, or patterns you can provide to achieve this.

A possible approach is to have something like:
GenerateFlowFile -> SplitText -> ExtractText -> InvokeHTTP -> further processing


GenerateFlowFile - you'd have multiple instances, with custom text as content of the flow file, and it'd contain one URL per line. You can have something like 10k URLs per GFF processor and have 20 instances of the GFF processor.
SplitText - creates one flow file per line, the content of the flow file being the URL to query
ExtractText - to extract the content of the flow file as a flow file attribute
InvokeHTTP to do the query by referencing the flow file attribute. You'd want to carefully choose the run schedule value of the processor to limit how many requests you're sending. You could set to 1s or 500ms or whatever value that works for your use case.

You can then do further processing with the results you get from the API calls.
